# Format decimal number after conversion from Integer

Tags: java, decimalformat

I need to convert an integer to a decimal number and then format it with precision 2, 3, 4 or 5 decimal depending upon certian conditions.

So I have used this code:

```
public  NumberFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    public static NumberFormat decimalFormatter3 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.000");
    public static NumberFormat decimalFormatter4 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0000");
    public static NumberFormat decimalFormatter5 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00000");
    public void run(Integer numeroDecimali, Articoli articoli){
        if(numeroDecimali == null || numeroDecimali == 2)
            super.setValueAt(articoli.getPrezzoTot()!=null ? 
                    decimalFormatter.format(articoli.getPrezzoTot()) : "", rowIndex, 7);
        else if(numeroDecimali == 3)
            super.setValueAt(articoli.getPrezzoTot()!=null ? 
                    decimalFormatter3.format(articoli.getPrezzoTot()) : "", rowIndex, 7);
        else if(numeroDecimali == 4)
            super.setValueAt(articoli.getPrezzoTot()!=null ? 
                    decimalFormatter4.format(articoli.getPrezzoTot()) : "", rowIndex, 7);
        else if(numeroDecimali == 5)
            super.setValueAt(articoli.getPrezzoTot()!=null ? 
                    decimalFormatter5.format(articoli.getPrezzoTot()) : "", rowIndex, 7);
```

I put the number of decimal and with decimalFormat(2,3,4,5) I can format the text.
This code works but, is there a way to accomplish this without so many IF statements? Is there a way to combine the information of numeroDecimali to optimize the code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
String.format( "%,." + numeroDecimali + "f", articoli.getPrezzoTot() );
```

Just make sure, `numeroDecimali` has a valid value.